# Docusign embedded signing not working in chrome

Tags: docusignapi

I have successfully integrated docusign embedd signing in our website

https://impulsedecisions.ae/agreement

It works well in mozilla. But it is not working in google chrome.

it shows the url

https://demo.docusign.net/Signing/startinsession.aspx?t=6fcbfcbf-da5a-41d4-a771-8b2dab3ca14d&AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1#&pat=1

with a white screen.

Comment: Please add your json to the question. You can get your json from the api logger

Comment: &AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1#&pat=1    . This parameter is automatically added in url, when i am remove this it works fine.