# Docusign throwing exception after drawing the signature and then adopting the sign and clicking on finish button

Tags: docusignapi

We are using Docusign in our website using envelopes. So we are using the API's and Iframe to display the docusign UI for signing in our site. Recently we are facing an issue in which we get an error in the iframe when we draw the signature and adopt it and then click on finish button in order to generate an envelope and send it.

The error does not give any technical specifications as to why it is happening. Also, it is only happening in Chrome. Please refer to screencast https://www.screencast.com/t/ZNh4Xm9z1Oc for details.

Comment: See [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44152977/docusign-embedded-signing-not-working-in-chrome) for a possible similar issue

Comment: Sorry, I don't use flash. Make a mov available. Or upload to YouTube. Or better, take a couple of screen shots of the key screens.

Comment: I suggest that you not use an iFrame. They only add trouble. Why do you think you need an iFrame? Just redirect to the DocuSign site.

Comment: is this still an issue?